# How to give Java more memory reliably?

Tags: java, memory

For a specific java program I needed more memory then the standard amount, but I cannot use command line to get more because it uses a launcher.

I tried adding "-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" to the runtime parameters in the Java Control Panel, this worked once but the next time I started the program the memory was back to the low default.
How can I reliably get more memory for this program?

Comment: maybe you can create a shortcut with the custom parameters?

Comment: like I said, I cannot use command line to start it, I do not know what parameters it uses to start the .jar. Also, the launcher updates the program so it's not an option to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .exe launcher appeared to in turn update and launch a .jar launcher.
I fixed the problem by simply adding the memory parameters to a command line command to start the .jar launcher. It doesn't automatically update the launcher this way but it's good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Most launchers (at least the ones I saw) give you the option to apply jvm parameters. This is where you can add your `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`. For instance in [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), you can set it like this:

[image: Launch4J JRE settings]

You can see at the bottom, that you can also put in your own parameters, though the memory stuff is already given as an individual option. I bet your launcher app can do that too.

Comment: This launcher does not, it has an option to select the amount of memory to use, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: @KelvinBongers What launcher are you using? And how are you using it? Because if there is an option to configure what you want and it doesn't do the trick, then either this is a bug of the launcher or you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

WHy not write a simple java process that just bootstraps your main process?

So the launcher launches process A, which in turn launches process B with the parameters you require?

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your launcher, there's a function call similar to this....

```
 JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm)
 {

JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption options;
strcpy(options.optionString, CLASSPATH); //fix for options.optionString = CLASSPATH;
if (DEBUG) printf("optionString = %s\n", options.optionString); 
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = &options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**) &env, &vm_args);
if (ret < 0) printf("\n<<<<< Unable to Launch JVM >>>>>\n");
return env;
}
```

right? if that is the case, just add those options to the optionsString.

sounds like you'll either hardcode it, or supply a .config file for the launcher that sets such properties. but the change definately goes to the launcher.

Comment: I did not make the program, I do not have source access.

Comment: you cant use command line, you can't make a shortcut, you can't make codechanges and the only thing that worked was to manually do it in the java control panel.

.... i dont wanna be rude but it sounds like you already have a working solution then?

Comment: It worked once and then stopped working for some reason, I have no idea why. I would like to not sound so vague but it's just exactly what happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot control the launcher, you have to create your own Java launcher.

Your current launcher can start the JAR and it can start the JAR again with the correct JVM args. i.e. a JAR can use Runtime.exec() to run itself (the same main or a different one) with the arguments you need to run your program.

AFAIK, You can't use the control panel to control java run via the command line. If it doesn't work now, I suspect it never really worked, perhaps it didn't matter that it wasn't working.